# Doubt in comprehension of the following sentence in the given paragraph

Tags: sentence-meaning, comprehension

**Link of the article :-** https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2022/jan/09/are-we-witnessing-the-dawn-of-post-theory-science

"With the benefit of hindsight, we can say that what Anderson saw is true (he wasn’t alone). The complexity that this wealth of data has revealed to us cannot be captured by theory as traditionally understood. “We have leapfrogged over our ability to even write the theories that are going to be useful for description,” says computational neuroscientist Peter Dayan, director of the Max Planck Institute for Biological Cybernetics in Tübingen, Germany. "**We don’t even know what they would look like.**" "

Does the concerned person mean how would the theories look like ? Due to them being very complex in nature, they are unexplainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "unexplainable". If it were "explainable" then it must have been written (or perhaps spoken or even expressed in some other form). I think the words "inexpressable" or "indefinable" or "indescribable" are better. (I first thought of "unexpressable" but the online dictionaries seem to prefer "inexpressible".)

The statement says they do not know enough to write down (or speak, etc) a description of the theory of [the subject matter]. I think complexity of the topic is relevant. Note an earlier part of the text *"We have leapfrogged over our ability to even write the theories ..."*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)